# How to remove this suspicious row of zeroes in the table?

Tags: r, rows

My code as follows

```
    got = read.csv("battles.csv")
    got = got[!(is.na(got$attacker_king) | got$attacker_king==""), ]
    got = got[!(is.na(got$region) | got$region == ""), ]
```

There were missing values for the variables, but removed it using code above

```
    spiderR = table(got$attacker_king, got$region)
    spiderR
```

when I tried running above code it shows:

```
                           Beyond the Wall The Crownlands The North The Reach The Riverlands
                                         0              0         0         0              0
  Balon/Euron Greyjoy                    0              0         5         2              0
  Joffrey/Tommen Baratheon               0              0         2         0              9
  Robb Stark                             0              1         1         0              6
  Stannis Baratheon                      1              1         2         0              0

                           The Stormlands The Westerlands
                                        0               0
  Balon/Euron Greyjoy                   0               0
  Joffrey/Tommen Baratheon              2               1
  Robb Stark                            0               2
  Stannis Baratheon                     1               0
```

Why are there zeroes in the first row?

Comment: Please include the output of `dput(got)`.

Comment: Which results do you get when running `levels(got$attacker_king)` and `levels(got$region)` ?

Comment: @LeoP. Can you please type in full code because I didn't quite understand it. Thank you.

Comment: @R18 You were right. I can see an extra "" . But my intention of putting "" in the code above was to remove the blank spaces. Can you guide me what to do next? Thank you.

Comment: Just type `dput(got)` in the command line after you loaded your dataframe and paste the output that appears in your console into your question. This way we can use your data to test possible answers for your question.

Answer (score 1):

If in `levels(got$attacker_king)` you have a non - expected factor, you can take a subset of your `got` table and run again your code. That is:

```
     # Define the subset of interest 
       subset.got <- got[got$attacker_king!="",]
     # Redefine the factor
       subset.got$attacker_king <- factor(subset.got$attacker_king)
     # Run just what you did before
       spideR <- table(subset.got$attacker_king, subset.got$region)
       spideR
```